Formatting month to the single digit with pandas
I have below code
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(['8/23/1999']).strftime("%m/%d/%Y").astype('str')

This generates 08/23/1999
However I want to get 8/23/1999
Is there any specific formatting to be used for this case?

There is no need to call .astype('str') because the result of strftime is already a string.

Updated following the comment from
ouroboros1
The solution below works only on Linux
On Linux Pandas supports Glibc extensions (see man 3 strftime), so you can use the - flag.

Glibc provides some extensions for conversion specifications.  (These extensions are not specified in POSIX.1-2001, but a few other
systems provide similar features.)
Between the '%' character and the conversion specifier character, an optional flag and field width may be specified.

...

The following flag characters are permitted:

_      (underscore) Pad a numeric result string with spaces.
-      (dash) Do not pad a numeric result string.
0      Pad a numeric result string with zeros even if the conversion specifier character uses space-padding by default.
^      Convert alphabetic characters in result string to uppercase.
#      Swap the case of the result string.  (This flag works only with certain conversion specifier characters, and of these, it is only really useful with %Z.)


For example:
pd.to_datetime(['8/23/1999']).strftime("%-m/%d/%Y")

This would produce an Index object with a string formatted without the padding.
Index(['8/23/1999'], dtype='object')


This is Linux specific. For Windows, it would have to be pd.to_datetime(['8/23/1999']).strftime("%#m/%d/%Y").
